# Table specific queries vs one single generic query

Tags: mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I have a DB with various tables. I see myself writing various function of this form :

```
def getAgeAndHealthFromUser()
def getIDPriceLifeFromProduct()
def getIDFromUser()
def getPriceFromProduct()
def setIDFromUser()
def setPriceFromProduct()

.. and so on.
```

Basically I am selecting / setting multiple columns of different tables most of the time. I hope you get it.

That is when I [tried the generic function approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943407/good-design-for-modifying-various-combination-of-columns-in-a-table) which takes different column names, table name as input and does the work.

I want to know does this approach has any potential problems I might get into ? Is this the right thing to do design wise ?

Comment: Have you considered using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool?

Comment: While we're discussing bad ideas, have you considered generic math functions, e.g. `def getMathResult(operator, operand1, operand2)` or writing an object-oriented framework to replace array syntax and operators?

Comment: Do it once.  Then you will understand why you should never do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Its doable , however you need to considered in such API the below :

For Set API - Each table has different column and different data types .

For Get API - when you selecting  data you select columns ( your result set structure is different per query case  )  , however your query filter is different from use case to use case  .

You can consider interact with the API using some kind of generic Json interface  or something else , but at end you may pay for this extra generic API in performances .

Thanks